# How to match either one element or another with Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've searched around and can't see an answer to this, though it must(?) be simple?

Given something like:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <select></select>
</form>
```

I want to select either the input element or the select, not knowing in advance which it will be.

I've tried variations on this (where . is the form node):

```
./(input or select)
```

But I'm getting messages about invalid xpath. This is in Python 3.

Comment: Try to use `./*[self::input or self::select]`

Comment: `./*[.=input or .=select]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
//input | //select
```

or

```
//*[self::input or self::select]
```